# Boolean position of a point

Tags: geogebra

I want to have a point that belongs or not to a straight line dependanding on a boolean value.
I tried

(4.54, -1.82) a + (1 - a) Point(f)

in the definition of my point, where  (4.54, -1.82) is the curent random position, a the boolean name, f the straight line. But it does not work.

Any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must know that a boolean is not `0` or `1` , it's take `true` or `false` ,
so create an integer called *`n`* and write this : `n=if(a,1,0)`
then u can complete ur work as

```
(4.54, -1.82) n + (1 - n) Point(f)
```

otherwise  i don't know